# How to have Microsoft Word remember document passwords?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, security, microsoft-office, passwords

I am using the latest Microsoft Office apps on Windows, namely: Word, Excel and Powerpoint.

Word documents can have password based security. When you open a document, you have to input the correct password.

Is there a way to have Word "remember" the document password for a previously opened document?

Thanks!

I need to open the same

Comment: No. You must enter the password.

Comment: Or remove the password. Security can be done in many ways. Does not always have to be on the document itself.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do that is with a global add-in that had special custom coding in the Document Open event.

The easiest method would be if all documents used the same password, but unique passwords for groups of documents could also be done if each group also contained a custom tag (document variable). The documents could also be saved with a password automatically by custom coding in the Document Before Save event.

If unique passwords for each document where required then the passwords would need to be stored somewhere accessible to the global add-in and applied programmatically upon open.